# SQL Query sort by in groups

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi i need help with queries. here is my query & table structure.

```
SELECT *
FROM products_description a, products b
where a.products_id=b.products_id
AND b.products_status >0
AND a.products_name LIKE '%".$q."%'
ORDER BY b.products_quantity DESC LIMIT 10 


---------------------------------------------------
| products_id | products_name | products_quantity |
---------------------------------------------------
|     980     |       SOS     |        21         |
---------------------------------------------------
|     101     |       GOLD    |        9          |
---------------------------------------------------
|     232     |       BALL    |        1          |
---------------------------------------------------
|     422     |       SONG    |        O          | 
---------------------------------------------------
|     371     |       ALL     |        O          | 
---------------------------------------------------
|     72      |       FISH    |        O          | 
---------------------------------------------------
```

I would like it to sort so that it is alphabaticaly ordered(product_name) while keeping those with 0 quantity at the bottom. Typically, i would like such result:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| products_id | products_name | products_quantity |
---------------------------------------------------
|     980     |       Ball    |        1          |
---------------------------------------------------
|     101     |       GOLD    |        9          |
---------------------------------------------------
|     232     |       SOS     |        21         |
---------------------------------------------------
|     422     |       All     |        O          | 
---------------------------------------------------
|     371     |       FISH    |        O          | 
---------------------------------------------------
|     72      |       SONG    |        O          | 
---------------------------------------------------
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select ...
From products_description a
    Join products b
        On a.products_id=b.products_id
Where b.products_status >0
    And a.products_name LIKE '%".$q."%'
Order By Case When products_quantity = 0 Then 1 Else 0 End Asc
    ,  a.products_name Asc
Limit 10
```

Comment: Hey, i used yours and it works. But its actually: 
Order By Case When products_quantity = 0 Then 1 Else 0 End Asc
    , a.products_name

Comment: @Thomas: wow, that's a syntax I've never seen before! What does it mean `Then 1 Else 0`? I mean, how MySql apply 1 and 0 to fields? Thanks!!

Comment: @Marco - I'm using a Case expression to create another sort column. In short, I am telling it that the values equal zero should sort after the values not equal to zero.

Comment: @Thomas: +1 because this is great. I've learned something new today and I really appreciate this syntax. Thanks again, great post!!

Comment: @cybertai - Just reread your OP where you said you wanted to sort by name but with zero values at the bottom. Have adjusted my query to accomodate.

Comment: @Thomas: hey its really good use of **Case statement** in select query.I have never seen before.Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM products_description a, products b
where a.products_id=b.products_id
AND b.products_status >0
AND a.products_name LIKE '%".$q."%'
ORDER BY (b.products_quantity = 0) DESC, products_name LIMIT 10
```

I am not sure at the moment if you need to order the boolean expression `ASC` or `DESC` so just try out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not limited to 10 items, you could try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products_description a, products b
where a.products_id=b.products_id
AND a.products_quantity > 0
AND b.products_status >0
AND a.products_name LIKE '%".$q."%'
ORDER BY b.products_name, b.products_quantity DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM products_description a, products b
where a.products_id=b.products_id
AND a.products_quantity = 0
AND b.products_status >0
AND a.products_name LIKE '%".$q."%'
ORDER BY b.products_name
```